# Require literal type union to include certain literal types

Tags: typescript, union-types, generic-type-parameters

I have a class called `Theme`.

```
class Theme<T> {}
```

I want to make `T` be requried to extend `string`, and make sure that `'light' | 'dark'` is included in `T`.

Examples:

```
new Theme<'light' | 'dark'>() // Should work
new Theme<'light'>() // Shouldn't work because 'dark' isn't included
new Theme<string>() // Should work
new Theme<'rainbow'>() // Shouldn't work because 'light' and 'dark' aren't included
new Theme<'light' | 'dark' | 'rainbow'>() // Should work
```

Comment: Why do you want this?  The example code `class Theme<T> {}` is a bit too minimal to show a use case.  You're not even using `T` at all.  Generally speaking such a constraint would look like `type OrLightDark<T> = T | 'light' | 'dark'; class Theme<T extends string> { somethingThatCaresAboutT: OrLightDark<T> }` where you use `OrLightDark<T>` inside the class instead of just `T`.  This just adds `"light"` and `"dark"` to the domain without having to throw an error if it's left out, and then `Theme<'rainbow'>` is the same as saying `'rainbow' | 'light' | 'dark'`.

Comment: I didn't include properties because I wanted the example to be minimal.  `OrLightDark<T>` is a good idea, but in my case I wanted to **require `T`** to include light and dark.

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally make `T extends never` to disallow types that do not include `'light' | 'dark'`.

```
type DefaultThemes = 'dark' | 'light'

class Theme<T extends DefaultThemes extends T ? unknown : never> {}
```

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBDArgG2AFQBYQLYQGcoBeKAcgBNEAnAazKgB9zUBLAcy2DICgeBjVIgJFseCAB4MUCAA9gEAHYUicJGkw58ROQuWioAfijJFtRQHsA7oqgAuKIogA3CNQB8UAN4BfPk6soMXwJMjZObiZyKjoydwAKAEooAHoUqABlLAs0CigrCzoeAKCtSTCOLjik1PSsnNQKRTJgfMLaKAAjCH4UAmhKGnooVgJm1tZFQWQKCApiiEDgyQJgakn2BOS0zOzctqKS5dDqREnO62rtur3G8YOO7t7kfpZKyMRlaKGGGiUWkZTVAzOYLJZlULhKpRQaxGGnc6XLa1XYNPIFOhAA)

Warning: this can be confusing because if a bad `T` is given, you get this error:

```
Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'never'.
```